# Maybe something wrong with program-examples/tokens/create-token/solang/tests /create-token.ts?

Tags: spl, solang

Link is here: https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/blob/main/tokens/create-token/solang/tests/create-token.ts

It gives two examples. One for creating SPL tokens the other for NFTs. Going through the two I find no difference. I wonder if there should be a difference here:

```
const metadataAddress = await metaplex
  .nfts()
  .pdas()
  .metadata({ mint: mintKeypair.publicKey })
```

Both SPL token and NFTs use " metaplex.nfts() ", so I guess here is something miswritten. Should SPL token use metaplex.spl() or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NFTs on Solana are also derived from the SPL Token Program but with `decimals` field set to 0 to signify non-fungibility. If you look at the code linked, `createTokenMint` function takes different inputs for `decimals` field in both cases.

```
// For SPL Token 
const tx = await program.methods
      .createTokenMint(
        wallet.publicKey, // freeze authority
        9, // decimals for the mint
        tokenTitle, // token name
        tokenSymbol, // token symbol
        tokenUri // token uri (off-chain metadata)
      )

// For NFT
const tx = await program.methods
      .createTokenMint(
        wallet.publicKey,
        0, // decimals for the mint, 0 for NFTs "non-fungible"
        tokenTitle,
        tokenSymbol,
        tokenUri
      )
```